# Spring Data - Mongo DB - @TextIndexed over @DBRef

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, dbref

Is it possible somehow to search in String fields over @DBRef.
I have this @Document:

```
public class DocumentFileVersion {

    @TextIndexed
    @DBRef
    private OtherObject otherObject
```

and I will search in String fields of otherObject. Is there any possibility to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DBRef are designed to be queried by `id` reference only.

So it is not possible. You should rethink your schema structure.